# Cakephp subdomain ajax requests failing 500 Internal server error

Tags: cakephp, jquery, request

I am working on a CakePHP application where I create a sub domain via routing. Everything was working fine but suddenly the Ajax requests for Facebook & Twitter API calls are failing with

```
NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error
```

We have implemented subdomains for which we have used `session.cookie_domain` to share the session ( session cookies) among the subdomains (created virtually), which points to the profile page of each User.

Previously it was working fine; but after we implemented this session sharing among the sub domains, it began to give us this error.

Can anyone help?

Comment: It's almost impossible to guess what's wrong without seeing any relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your redirect/callback URL for both Twitter's and Facebook's API calls are being sent to a single "static" URL not the user specific subdomain.